# Pass Data List from angularjs to webservice?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework, cross-platform

I'm working on app in ionic 1 platform using angularjs, in which I want to Pass List of object to Web-service, How can I do it?

I have tried doing this but was not able to send any Data..

Here is my code and how to pass list of object in data: $scope.AddNew

```
$http({ url: $rootScope.HostName + '/bulk', dataType: 'json', method: 'POST', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data: $scope.AddNew, headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } }).success(function (response) { alert("Success"); }).error(function (error) { });
```

If there is another approach or way to do it then please do help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your request and response in question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your $http call is in the controller where you can access $scope.

The way you had passed is correct, but at the server side you should accept your request body as an Array of objects.

If your server side is java spring app,
You would design your method with @RequestBody YourClass[] objs

Comment: I'm using asp.net webservice with c#
How can I do in that?
If there is any example you can share would be of great help...

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct, just so it is simple and readable I would suggest this format:

```
$http.post($rootScope + '/bulk', $scope.AddNew).then(function(response) {
   alert("Success");
}, function(error) {

})
```

The promise structure in AngularJS has since been updated. In regard to your question, the code should work fine if you can access `AddNew` through your `$scope`. Make sure you are handling your requests properly in the backend. Try logging for checking if data is sent and received.

Comment: Sriram, I tried your suggestion but its not working.

Comment: Do you get any error in the response? If so can you post the log here?